# Magento - displaying a random review outside of review module

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento 1.5 and am attempting to include a small box in my sidebar for a random product showing a product image, product name, star rating and part of a review.

I have managed to get Magento displaying a random product in the sidebar, unfortunately I cannot seem to find a way to select the random product based on if it has a review or not, and I also cannot find a way to load a review summary into the sidebar template I'm using.

I found the following piece of example code but it just throws the good old call to non object error.

```
<?php

$storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$summaryData = Mage::getModel(‘review/review_summary’)
->setStoreId($storeId)
->load($_product->getId());

/* @var $summaryData Mage_Review_Model_Review_Summary */

/*

array(
['primary_id'] => 147
['entity_pk_value'] => 166
['entity_type'] => 1
['reviews_count'] => 1
['rating_summary'] => 80
['store_id'] => 1
)
*/

?>
```

if anyone has any ideas how to get this working, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because of the quotes you are using. Use ' instead.

In response to your edit, this is how you would go ahead and load 5 random products that have a review:

```
$review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
$collection = $review->getProductCollection();
$collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->getSelect()
                ->limit(5)
                ->order('rand()');
$review->appendSummary($collection);

foreach($collection as $product) {
        var_dump($product->debug());
}
```

Obviously now you can do something like:

```
$product->getRatingSummary()
```

to extract rating data, etc.

Of course it is up to you to create a block to put this in (or the bad way -> just put it in some template).

Have fun ;)

Third edit in response to your question:

```
/* Getting summary title / body. */
$title = $product->getTitle();
$body  = $product->getDetail();

/* To get (what I assume is) 'star' rating. */
$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary();
$starRating = $ratingSummary['rating_summary'];
```

Comment: well, that does remove the non object issue, not having much luck displaying any of the info now though.

Comment: wow, did not ever expect to be able to do that selection, let alone in such minimal code! thank you greatly! one final little question, the attributes don't seem to include the review details, how would one pull the review body and the star rating out?

Comment: I hadn't spotted `appendSummary()` before. Kudos.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of selecting a product by random and showing a review, i would rather select a review and load its related product.
This has 2 effects:
1. You automatically have a product that has a review.
2. Products with more reviews have an increased probability of being shown.

But thats just me ^^

Comment: I would love to do it that way, unfortunately I've not even found rumors of selecting a review without using the product id.

Comment: Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection();

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`Mage_Review_Model_Review::getEntitySummary()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Review/Mage_Review_Model_Review.html#getEntitySummary)

For simplicity Magento already provides a product collection cross referenced with reviews.

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('review/review_product_collection');
$products->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
$products->setPageSize(3);
foreach ($products as $product) {
    // Picks 3 random products with reviews.
    Mage::getSingleton('review/review')->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);
    $summary = $product->getRatingSummary();
    // $summary->getRatingSummary() = percentage of average rating values
}
```

Comment: Better to use appendSummary($collection) instead of getEntitySummary to avoid instantiating review/review_summary model for every product in the collection.